# How can I convert my query from MySQL to LINQ?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

How can I convert this query from MySQL to LINQ?

```
SELECT SUM(IF(x>0, c*(x/100),20.00)) AS x1 
FROM tablename 
WHERE uid="some value" AND name='some value';
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I would like to know , how to do calculations in LINQ

Comment: He asked what you tried, not what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sum =
    testlist.Where(item => item.name == "somevalue" && item.uid == "somevalue")
    .Sum(c => c.x > 0 ? c.c*(c.x/100) : 20);
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

try this tool.

http://softwaretopic.informer.com/sql-to-linq-converter-online-free/